# Issue with envsubst in Dockerfile for Environment Variable Substitution

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm encountering an issue with environment variable substitution using the envsubst command within a Dockerfile. While the same command works perfectly when executed in the Docker Desktop Exec terminal, it doesn't seem to produce the expected results when running from the Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM nginx:alpine
    RUN apk add --update gettext
    WORKDIR /etc/nginx/conf.d/
    COPY nginx.conf.template .
    
    # This line in the Dockerfile is not substituting environment variables correctly
    # RUN envsubst < nginx.conf.template > ../nginx.conf
    
    CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf.template:

```
    //...
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass $API_HOST:$API_PORT; //This is line 10
        }
    //...
```

#### Running this Dockerfile fials with:

```
2023/10/08 17:58:55 [emerg] 1#1: 
invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10
nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10
make: *** [Makefile:14: run-attached-wsl] Error 1
```

However, when I run the following command directly from the Docker Desktop Exec terminal, it works perfectly:

```
    envsubst < nginx.conf.template > ../nginx.conf
```

I've verified that the .env file, nginx.conf.template, and nginx.conf are all in the correct locations.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the envsubst command behaves differently when used in the Dockerfile compared to running it directly in the Docker Desktop Exec terminal. What could be the possible causes or solutions for this issue?

Comment: What effect are or aren't you seeing?  Note that the exec terminal path won't change the in-memory configuration the running Nginx process has and will get lost as soon as the container exits; I'd use that sparingly and not as a primary path to work with your container.

Comment: Also note that the Docker Hub `nginx` image already knows how to run `envsubst` on startup, which might get around whatever problem you're having.  See for example [this answer](/a/62844707).

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question with more details.

Comment: Where do the variables `API_HOST` and `API_PORT` get set?

Comment: I have a .env file and i expost the envs with the docker run command:
 docker run --name $(CONTAINER_NAME) -it -p 80:80 --env-file .env --rm  $(IMAGE_NAME)

Comment: First you `docker build` the image, then you `docker run --env-file .env` it.  If you `RUN envsubst` in the Dockerfile, it hasn't seen the `.env` file yet and it doesn't know what environment variables it will eventually be run with.